# Prevent popup from being closed on form submit HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to prevent my popup from being closed when the form is submitted, I tried to do this:

```
        <form class="popup-form" id="login-popup-form" method="post" onsubmit='return false;'>
            <label id="login-popup-user-label">Your username/email:</label> <input class="popup-input" id="login-popup-username-field" name="login-username" placeholder="Username"/><br />
            <label id="login-popup-pw-label">Your password:</label> <input class="popup-input" id="login-popup-password-field" name="login-password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
            <input id="login-popup-submit" type="submit" name="login-submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
```

But that also prevents the values from being sent. So is there a way to make sure the popup doesn't close but also send the values?

Comment: You need to use ajax to do that. ( if I got that question right )

Comment: When you submit a form the current page stops and a new one is served-up. The old page cannot preserve the pop-up because it is no longer in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common Javascript Framework (for Example Jquery) with $.post and $.serialize

Check this out:

http://blog.codeinside.eu/2010/02/09/howto-form-valuesinputs-ber-ajax-mit-jquery-serialize-bertragen/

Answer (score 0):

Form not just closed, when you send form browser load result (new page) from server, and there is no popup window opened. You can use ajax request to send data from form and prevent current page reload.

```
$("#login-popup-form").submit(function(e){ //when form submited
    e.preventDefault(); //do not submit form in default way
    form_data = $(this).serialize(); //get data out of form
    $.post('/url-to-send-data', form_data, function(data){ //send ajax request, when get result call function
        if(data.status==1)
           alert('all cool');
        else
            alert(data.message);
    });
});
```

you need jquery for this example to work, and json response from server when form posted

success example:

```
{status:1}
```

error example:

```
{status:0,message:"wrong password"}
```

you can use any other format for server response, but json is easiest for javascript to work with.

Comment: But I'm trying to add an error message if something went wrong in my PHP script (which connects to MySQL).

Comment: You can return json from server with error or success message and show it in current page. eg {status: 0, mesage: "Wrong login or password"} or {status: 1}, then in javscript check result and show error mesage or do success, ill add exmple to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend downloading and using jQuery because it already has the AJAX handler setup for you. See attached link for a list of examples and implementaion. Remember you will need to manually pull the values from the Form, and consider loading up a spinner while doing to so you don't get double submissions from the users.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/